# How to identify if the new apk is installed?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I'm creating an android library that will be embedded in to application source which will be used for recording some analytics information on the server. I wanted to find out if the user has upgraded to a new version of the application(not the library) using SDK API. I'm trying to avoid having the application developers change anything in the manifest to indicate the version change.  I already have a mechanism to identify each device on the server. In this case is there a way to identify if the .apk is upgraded when the tries to contact the server?

So far I found PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime is changed. I thought PackageInfo.signatures content will change too, but it is not changed even when I change the application code. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just send along `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`? If the value is different than the last value received, it's been updated. For an application to be updated, the version code must be at least as large as the previous version. To be published on the Google Play store, the version code must be increased.

Comment: `For an application to be updated` - not fully true. It's just Google Play store requirement. If you side load (like during development), then it is not required.

Comment: No, it's still required to *upgrade*. If you uninstall and reinstall the application, then it doesn't matter what the version number is. To *upgrade* the installation (`adb install -r <path-to-apk>`) the versionCode must change.

Comment: If upgrade for you means installing over existing installation then you can do that w/o touching versionCode.

Comment: Updated to clarify that the version code must be *at least* as large rather than necessarily larger.